# Variables will not ouput

Tags: javascript

I have tried to define two separate variables and then manipulate them However, I am having several syntax errors (I am not great with JavaScript) both variables should be output but only `loc_name` is

```
// User Vars
var LOC_NAME = ("Manchester"); 
var LOC_NAME2 = ("liverpool");

// <....> Code I cannot share-

if(thisLoc.getName() == LOC_NAME) {
    Logger.log("Campaign: " + thisCampaign.getName());
    thisLoc.setBidModifier(adj);
    Logger.log("Bid Modifier Set to " + adj);

else(thisLoc.getName() == LOC_NAME2) {
    Logger.log("Campaign: " + thisCampaign.getName());
    thisLoc.setBidModifier(adj);
    Logger.log("Bid Modifier Set to " + adj);
}
}
```

Comment: developer tools console will show you an error, no doubt ... change `else(...` to `} else if(...` ... note the CLOSING }

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` before the `else`, and have one too many at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to control the flow with a properly formated `if-else-if` block, like so...

```
// User Vars
var LOC_NAME = ("Manchester"); 
var LOC_NAME2 = ("liverpool");

// <....> Code you cannot share-

if (thisLoc.getName() == LOC_NAME) {

    Logger.log("Campaign: " + thisCampaign.getName());
    thisLoc.setBidModifier(adj);
    Logger.log("Bid Modifier Set to " + adj);

}  else if (thisLoc.getName() == LOC_NAME2) {

    Logger.log("Campaign: " + thisCampaign.getName());
    thisLoc.setBidModifier(adj);
    Logger.log("Bid Modifier Set to " + adj);

}
```

See [MDN: if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)